# Trying to create a callback function to get ID's of 3 different img elements using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm trying to create a callback function that will retrieve the specific id from 1 of 3 different clicked images. The images correlate to either rock, paper, or scissors. I want to be able to grab the id from the clicked image and use it to compare to the computers choice to determine a winner. I will include a codepen and my code bellow.

Thanks in advance!

https://codepen.io/constequalsexcel/pen/MWwjjKa

```
HTML
'''
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <title>Rock Paper Scicssors Game</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>Rock, Paper, Scissors!</header>
        <h4>Choose your weapon!</h4>
        <div class="images">
            <img src="images/rock.png" id="rock" onclick="userChoiceFunction()" />

            <img src="images/paper.png" id="paper" onclick="userChoiceFunction()" />

            <img
                src="images/scissors.png"
                id="scissors"
                onclick="userChoiceFunction()"
            />
        </div>

        <h4 id="computer-message"></h4>
        <div class="outcome-messages"></div>

        <script src="scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
'''

CSS
''' 
header {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h4 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 100px 0 60px 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
}

.images {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.images > button {
    margin-right: 30px;
    -ms-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.images > button:hover {
    margin-right: 30px;
    border: 2px solid green;
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.images img {
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px 30px 0 30px;
}
'''
JS
'''
// click one of three images (rock, paper, or scissors) on screen
// computer randomly chooses one also (rock, paper or scissors)
// compare user selected and computer selected choices
// determine if user or computer wins
// dispaly result to the browser
// start process over so user can play again..

// get the id of clicked img
// set variable equal to img id
// pass variable to function to compare to computers choice



// generate random numbers for computer choice
// set random number equal to rock, paper, or scissors
// set variable equal to computers choice
let computerChoice = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3);
if (computerChoice === 1) {
    computerChoice = 'rock';
} else if (computerChoice === 2) {
    computerChoice = 'paper';
} else {
    computerChoice = 'scissors';
}
//console.log(computerChoice);

/*
if (computerChoice === userChoice) {
    document.getElementById('computer-message').innerHTML = 'It was a tie!';
} else if (computerChoice === 'paper' && userChoice === 'scissors') {
    document.getElementById('computer-message').innerHTML =
        'The computer chose paper! You win!';
} else if (computerChoice === 'paper' && userChoice === 'rock') {
    document.getElementById('computer-message').innerHTML =
        'Computer chose paper! You lose!';
} else if (computerChoice === 'rock' && userChoice === 'paper') {
    document.getElementById('computer-message').innerHTML =
        'Computer chose rock! You win!';
}
*/
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this...

```
let imgChoice = document.querySelectorAll('.images img');
imgChoice.forEach(function(el, index) {
  el.addEventListener('click', compareChoice(el.id));
});
```

So grab the image elements, loop over them and add a click event for all of them that when they click on it, it runs a function. I called mine "compareChoice". This function can then grab what the computer choice is and compare it to the id passed to it.